# Send email to any domain address

Tags: c#, .net, email

I have a code for sending email from one gmail to another:

```
MailMessage o = new MailMessage("from@gmail.com", "to@gmail.com", "Subject", "Body");
NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential("from@gmail.com", "password");
SmtpClient smtpobj = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
smtpobj.EnableSsl = true;
smtpobj.Credentials = netCred;
smtpobj.Send(o);
```

I sent to gmail domain address but I want to send email to any domain addresses (..@domain1.com, ..@domain2.com, ...). 
**Is there a way to do that ?**

Comment: i don't get what you mean. You can send email to any email address with the above code.

Comment: All you need to do is pass the appropriate strings as parameters to your function.

Comment: Just change the email addresses and SMTPClient to the desired ones and it should work

Comment: What is the challenge you are facing? Any error message?

Comment: @J.McCabe If I'm not wrong, you do not need to change the SMTP Client as that is for sender's email.

Comment: @active92   yeah, you're right  :)   typing without thinking. My bad....

Comment: @active92, thanks for your remark. It really works. It seems I cought exception becouse of gmail protection. But I wasn't sure that SmtpClient is only for sender.

Answer (score 2):

I m not sure to understand the question, the code bellow will send an email to : `to@gmail.com`, `to@domain1.com` and `to@domain2.com`

```
NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential("from@gmail.com", "password");
SmtpClient smtpobj = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
smtpobj.EnableSsl = true;
smtpobj.Credentials = netCred;

string[] Domains = { "gmail.com", "domain1.com", "domain2.com" };

foreach (var domain in Domains)
{
    MailMessage o = new MailMessage("from@gmail.com", "to@" + domain, "Subject", "Body");
    smtpobj.Send(o);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I am not fluent with C#, although I don't know a programming language that doesn't allow concatenation. Concatenation is basically combining multiple string values into one. I personally would have a variable with the .net address in it.

*(EX:string address = "yahoo.com")*

and then concatenate it with your string of text.

*(EX:("from@"+address, "to@"+address, "Subject", "Body"))*

And with variables you can have lists in them and probably call object # from __ list,or have the variable set as user input, etc.

See this website for some more info:
[Concatenation in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx)

I also suggest looking at examples of code that have the same objective. Have fun and happy trails!

Comment: Just added some more information pertaining to what I think his/her question is asking. If not concatenation, I hope there was some information that I provided that may be of benefit. I like to make an attempt at helping, because if it does help that's good, if it doesn't well no harm in trying <3